# Divide grand total of sales for store format to grand total of sales for each store

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, olap-cube

I have an OLAP cube and I have created a PivotTable. I want to get all sales for each store format (ex. STANDARD, MAXI, MINI) then grand total for each store will be divided to the grand total for his format.

If a store is a STANDARD format, the grand total for that store to be divided by the grand total of sales for STANDARD format.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

I want something like this .... This is the formula I use atm and it works, but the file becomes slow and I want to use Pivot Table ...

```
SUM(((SUMIFS(SalesFormatAll[Known Losses Amt AY];SalesFormatAll[Sites.Site Type 02];[@Format];SalesFormatAll[Merchandise Structure.Level 02 Desc];$B$5;SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Week No Retail];$B$3;SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Month Name];$B$2)+SUMIFS(SalesFormatAll[Unknown Losses Amt AY];SalesFormatAll[Sites.Site Type 02];[@Format];SalesFormatAll[Merchandise Structure.Level 02 Desc];$B$5;SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Week No Retail];$B$3;SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Month Name];$B$2))/SUMIFS(SalesFormatAll[Sales Net Amt AY];SalesFormatAll[Sites.Site Type 02];[@Format];SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Week No Retail];$B$3;SalesFormatAll[Calendar.Month Name];$B$2;SalesFormatAll[Merchandise Structure.Level 02 Desc];$B$5))))))))))))));"")
```

Comment: What is wrong with using functions like sum() and sumifs() - will work well with or without pivottable.

Comment: When I apply filters it won't return the right result. I also have categories for each store and so on ... I need the grand total of sales for each format to remain a constant.

Comment: Then work with the original data - avoids any filter problems.

Comment: I have over 1 mil rows ... I need to use Pivot Table. If I use data my file have 110MB or 45MB saved as xlsb

Comment: Then use other programs to deal with the data  - used to be part of a team where the data was 100meg of just numbers in a csv format - wrote the programs to split out all the detail needed and ended up with nearly 200,000 files showing every thing we could think relevant. SAS was used for that - fantastically powerful but it has a learning curve (like climbing Everest :) )